# Best questions (by vote) from last day, days, week

Tags: discussion, bug

Very strange to upvote questions and then going back to vote sorting tab to see question which is one year old. It would be best to see good questions from past day, days week month.

So in current form upvoting a question makes no sense. To me.

Thank you for thinking about this message.

Comment: I'm confused. If you want them sorted by time why don't you use the "newest" tab?

Comment: it does not sort by time and most voted up, or does it?

Comment: Why is it so important WHEN a good (highly upvoted) question was asked? Good questions have no expiration date ...

Comment: @Dilaton - you are mixing 2 different things. In global its not important at all. In local i want to follow up most "interesting" questions, not just browse new once or high activity ones.

Comment: People dont understand. What is sense to upvote? There are many interesting questions which got 3 or 5 upvotes and they will sink forever in the last tabs (you have to browse to the last pages of vote tab) of 700 best questions with average vote number lest say being 5.

Comment: And seriously cooling tea with the spoon, best question for the world physics-related community? :) Really? :D Funny funny stuff.

Comment: Now if you just go to http://physics.stackexchange.com you have the tabs "active" , "featured", "hot", "week", "month". I dont remember if it was there before :) since i was always first pressing "Questions",  but i like it! :) Question answered.

Answer (score 4):

If you can tolerate a less that fully up-to-date picture of the site, you can construct arbitrary queries on the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com has exact tabs which we are discussing here :) without pressing Quesions.